# Data visualization in R matrix printing

Tags: r, matrix, package, data-visualization

**Problem:** 
I'm trying to print a matrix with large fields, this leads to an unreadable matrix in R console:

[image: R console matrix print]

I know that Rstudio can show a well-formatted matrix like so:
[image: Rstudio matrix print]

However, I'd rather not use Rstudio since it crashes often. I was wondering if there was a package or a trick in R to display objects in a nice/readable format (something close or better than what Rstudio is doing)

**Reproducible code:**

```
a <- matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=0)
large <- paste("some_string_",1:200,sep=" ")
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
a <- rbind(a,toString(large))
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible matrix which can't be displayed adequately?

Comment: I added that in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your test data, I like how the plain old R Console does more than how R Studio does it. In any event, depending on what you want, the function [View](http://127.0.0.1:30298/library/utils/html/View.html) might help. With your test data, `View(a)` displays something which looks like:

[image]

If this isn't what the sort of thing that you want, it shouldn't be too hard to write your own matrix pretty-printer.

Comment: View() does make the output more readable. I didn't know about that function...thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`tibble`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/tibble.pdf)package?

Comment: it doesn't show the column/variable that contains large fields. I get the following error: "Variables not shown: Mymatrix[, 2] <chr>." with only the first column being displayed. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Try to subset that column using for example `select ()` from `dplyr`